# How do I resolve this error that comes in R,Shiny inspite of specifying the environment?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, environment

I am trying to display a map and a plot here in a tab interface using Shiny package in R. Inspite of setting the environment by calling the environment(), I am getting this error. The code snippet is given below:

server.R :

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$box <- renderPlot({
  filtered<- aleast.scores[aleast.scores$team == input$typeInput , ]
  ggplot(data=filtered) +
  geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=score, fill=team), binwidth=1) + 
  #facet_grid(team~.) +
  theme_bw() + scale_color_brewer() +
  labs(title="MOBILE PHONE REVIEW")  
})
  output$map <- renderPlot({
  long <-locations_f$longitude
  lat <- locations_f$latitude
  worldMap <- map_data("world")
  zp1 <- ggplot(worldMap,environment=environment())
  zp1 <- zp1 + geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group), #Draw map
                       colour = gray(2/3), lwd = 1/3)
  filtered<- locations_f[locations_f$team == input$typeInput , ]    
  zp1 <- zp1 + geom_point(data = filtered, #Add points indicating users
                        aes(x = long, y = lat, color=type), 
                        alpha = 1, size = 1.5)#+facet_grid(team~.)# +
  zp1<-zp1+theme_bw() # + scale_color_brewer()
  zp1 <- zp1 + theme_minimal()
  print(zp1)
  })

})
```

UI.R
    library(shiny)

```
# Define UI for random distribution application 
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),

  # Sidebar with controls to select the random distribution type
  # and number of observations to generate. Note the use of the
  # br() element to introduce extra vertical spacing
  sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("typeInput", "Product type",
               choices = c("motorola","nexus","iphone")),
      br()
    ),

    # Show a tabset that includes a plot, summary, and table view
    # of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
              tabPanel("plot", plotOutput("box")), 
              tabPanel("Map", plotOutput("map"))
      )
    )
  )
))
```

And This is the error I am getting

> Warning: Error in exists: argument "env" is missing, with no default
>
> Stack trace (innermost first):
>
> ```
> 68: output$box
>  1: shiny::runApp
> ```

Also the program worked fine when the first graph (MOBILE PHONE REVIEW) was alone plotted without any tab interface

Comment: Your example isn't reproducible. What's `aleast.scores`?

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a reproducible example, so I made up some data, and the app ran fine. Try updating your packages.

I made some changes:

- replaced `geom_bar` with `geom_histogram` to deal with the `Warning: 'geom_bar() no longer has a 'binwidth' parameter. Please use 'geom_histogram()' instead.`
- replaced `long` and `lat` in `geom_point(data = filtered, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color=type), alpha = 1, size = 1.5)` since you want the colours to be from the filtered data

**server.R**

```
aleast.scores <- data.frame(score = runif(100, min = 0, max = 10), team = sample(c("motorola","nexus","iphone"), 100, replace = TRUE))

locations_f <- data.frame(latitude = runif(100, min = -35, max = 35), longitude = runif(100, min = -120, max = 150), team = sample(c("motorola","nexus","iphone"), 100, replace = TRUE), type = sample(c("good phone", "crap phone"), 100, replace = TRUE))

library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$box <- renderPlot({
    filtered<- aleast.scores[aleast.scores$team == input$typeInput , ]
    ggplot(data=filtered) +
      geom_histogram(mapping=aes(x=score, fill=team), binwidth=1) + 
      #facet_grid(team~.) +
      theme_bw() + scale_color_brewer() +
      labs(title="MOBILE PHONE REVIEW")  
  })
  output$map <- renderPlot({
    long <-locations_f$longitude
    lat <- locations_f$latitude
    worldMap <- map_data("world")
    zp1 <- ggplot(worldMap,environment=environment())
    zp1 <- zp1 + geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group), #Draw map
                           colour = gray(2/3), lwd = 1/3)
    filtered<- locations_f[locations_f$team == input$typeInput , ]    
    zp1 <- zp1 + geom_point(data = filtered, #Add points indicating users
                            aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color=type), 
                            alpha = 1, size = 1.5)#+facet_grid(team~.)# +
    zp1<-zp1+theme_bw() # + scale_color_brewer()
    zp1 <- zp1 + theme_minimal()
    print(zp1)
  })

})
```

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Tabsets"),

  # Sidebar with controls to select the random distribution type
  # and number of observations to generate. Note the use of the
  # br() element to introduce extra vertical spacing
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("typeInput", "Product type",
                   choices = c("motorola","nexus","iphone")),
      br()
    ),

    # Show a tabset that includes a plot, summary, and table view
    # of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                  tabPanel("plot", plotOutput("box")), 
                  tabPanel("Map", plotOutput("map"))
      )
    )
  )
))
```